# Degrade Windows10 to Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10

I bought a new laptop with win10 installed by default. Is it possible to degrade it to Windows 8.1?

As far I know, it can be degraded only if it is upgraded to Win10 but not for default installation.

Thanks!

Comment: [Any downgrade rights would be offered by the OEM.](https://www.microsoft.com/OEM/en/licensing/sblicensing/Pages/downgrade_rights.aspx)  So contact OEM of your machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to downgrade from a fresh Windows 10 install as you only have a license for Windows 10 and not Windows 8.1. The only time it is possible to downgrade is if you upgraded from a previous Windows installation.

Comment: [It certainly is possible to downgrade your Windows 10 license to Windows 8.1](https://www.microsoft.com/OEM/en/licensing/sblicensing/Pages/downgrade_rights.aspx)

Comment: @Ramhound that is only possible for the Pro editions of Windows. If SSS is running a home or any other edition of Windows he is not going to be able to do that.

Comment: My response to you is that.  It is possible if using a Pro edition, so if SSS is running a Pro version, they can do that.  My point, your answer to indicate "it is not possible" is premature

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't do a direct upgrade from Windows 7/8/8.1 to Windows 10, you won't be able to just Downgrade - Additionally, if you did upgrade, but removed the Windows.old folder, you will also not be able to downgrade/revert back.

So, in your case, since your laptop came with Windows 10, the only thing you can do is Fresh install of Windows 8.1. You can either use a DVD of Windows, or download the ISO from Microsoft's Website and create a bootable media.

Comment: While he could install Windows 8.1, without a license, it wouldn't be usable as a licensed product.